# AngularJS rows ordering in table

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have in my html page simple table with the possibility to sort rows by clicking on headers:

```html
<table class="table-bordered table-striped table" style="width: 800px;">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='id';sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                ID
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                      ng-show="sortType=='id' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
                      ng-show="sortType=='id' && sortReverse"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='name';sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                Name
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                      ng-show="sortType=='name' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
                      ng-show="sortType=='name' && sortReverse"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='desiredResolutionDate';sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                Desired Date
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                      ng-show="sortType=='desiredResolutionDate' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
                      ng-show="sortType=='desiredResolutionDate' && sortReverse"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='urgency';sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                Urgency
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                      ng-show="sortType=='urgency' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
                      ng-show="sortType=='urgency' && sortReverse"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType='state';sortReverse=!sortReverse">
                State
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
                      ng-show="sortType=='state' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
                      ng-show="sortType=='state' && sortReverse"></span>
            </a>
        </th>
        <th>
            Action
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="ticket in allTickets | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse|filter:searchTicket">
        <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
        <td><a href="#">{{ticket.name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{ticket.desiredResolutionDate}}</td>
        <td>{{ticket.urgency}}</td>
        <td>{{ticket.state}}</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="btn"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller part:

```
$scope.sortType = 'urgency';
$scope.sortReverse = false;
```

And it works, but if user click, for example, on "urgency" header, and I have 4 types of urgencies ('Critical','High','Medium','Low') it will sort rows in this order: 'Critical'->'High'->'Low'->'Medium', but I don't want to sort by characters, I want to sort by descending urgencies, like 'Critical'->'High'->'Medium'->'Low'.

Comment: Read the doumentation of the orderBy filter. it explains how to use a function that returns the values on which the comparisons must be made. Also, filter before searching: that would make things faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add another property to ticket as urgencyNumber

```
1 for critical
2 for high
3 for medium
4 for low
```

and order by urgencyNumber when user clicks on sort by urgency

**update**

if you cannot add urgencyNumber in server side you can loop through allTickets  and set urgencyNumber in controller

```
angular.forEach($scope.allTickets, function (value, key) {

    if (value.urgency == "critical") {
        value.urgencyNumber = 1;
    }
    else if (value.urgyncy = "high") {
        value.urgencyNumber = 2;
    }

    ...
});
```

and if you change your html to this

```
<a href="#" ng-click="sortType='urgencyNumber';sortReverse=!sortReverse">Urgency
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
            ng-show="sortType=='urgencyNumber' && !sortReverse"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
            ng-show="sortType=='urgencyNumber' && sortReverse"></span>
</a>
```

now when user clicks on sort by urgency items will be sorted by urgencyNumber

Comment: I would be very grateful to you if you could explain how it would look in controller. I am very new to angularjs, so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much